# Estoy intentando subir un excel que tiene mas de 300mil filas con php

Tags: php, archivo, csv

tengo un código que sube archivos CSV o xls a una tabla que tengo creada en la base de datos, el problema es que el excel que intento subir tiene más de trescientas mil filas, osea más de trecientos mil registros y no los sube todos, solo sube como 200 maximo 900 registros.

A que se debe esto?

este es mi codigo:

index.php

```
<form action="subirexcel.php" method="post" name="frmExcelImport" id="frmExcelImport" enctype="multipart/form-data">


<input type="file" name="file" id="file-1" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.csv" style="color:#ffffff;" required />
      
<br><br>                
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="import" class="md-trigger" value="Subir Archivo">
</form>
```

subirexcel.php

```
<?php
include('dbconect.php');
require_once('vendor/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require_once('vendor/SpreadsheetReader.php');



if (isset($_POST["import"]))
{
    
$allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/csv','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];
  
  if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType)){

        $targetPath = 'subidas/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);
        
        $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);
        
        $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());
        for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++)
        {
            
            $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);
            
            foreach ($Reader as $Row)
            {
          
                
                $cliente = "";
                if(isset($Row[0])) {
                    $cliente = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[0]);
                }
                
                
                $refe = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $refe = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[1]);
                }
                
                $v_utc = "";
                if(isset($Row[2])) {
                    $v_utc = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[2]);
                }
                
                
                
                
                
                
                if (!empty($cliente) || !empty($refe) || !empty($v_utc)) {
                    $query = "insert into data_vbox(cliente,refe,v_utc) values('".$acliente."','".$refer."','".$v_utc."')";
                    $resultados = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                
                
                    if (! empty($resultados)) {
                        echo "<script>alert('Excel importado correctamente! Datos de VBOX')
                             window.location='index.php';</script>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<script>alert('Hubo un problema al importar registros!')
                             window.location='index.php';</script>";
                    }
                }
             }
        
         }
  }
  else
  { 
        echo "<script>alert('El archivo enviado es invalido. Por favor vuelva a intentarlo!')
              window.location='index.php';</script>";
  }
}
?>
```

No se de que forma puedo optimizar el código para que suba todos los registros que estén en el excel, es decir si en el excel tengo 1 millón de registros la idea es que suba todo.

Cualquier ayuda me podría ser de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Comment: a lo mejor tu servidor de base de datos tiene alguna restricción en la cantidad de datos o tiempo de ejecución; sabes si sale algún error por pantalla o en los logs???

Comment: No sale ningun error, de hecho ejecuta todo el codigo muy bien y sube registros pero muy pocos, no los sube todos.

Comment: bueno puedes hacer un test de prueba y en ves de subir los datos al mysql intenta tirarlo por pantalla a ver que te sale...

Comment: aunque me parece que el error esta en que: _por cada linea estas haciendo el insert; en algún momento el mysql se cansa de recibir datos y se desconecta creo que son 300 segundos; te recomiendo hacerlo de otra manera; prepara todos los datos a como deben ser insertados y cuando ya estén preparado realiza solo un insert .... con una sola conexión._

Comment: Cuando yo hago una tarefa larga añado el comando set_time_limit(0) al principio del código para que no se perca el contacto con el servidor.